# Easiest way to connect iPhone and Mac over WiFi with "server client" model

Tags: objective-c, iphone, networking, macos, bonjour

I am interested in creating a server application on the Mac and a client application on the iPhone. The iPhone would send commands to the Mac through this connection.

What's the easiest way to do this? I've seen NS/CFNetServices discussed here:

[Ad Hoc Wifi Connection Between iPhone & Mac - Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848525/ad-hoc-wifi-connection-between-iphone-mac-possible)

but I'm wondering if that's a little too complicated for what I'm trying to do. Is there a tutorial or example project that walks me through this? Better yet, is there something GameKit-like (in simplicity and functionality) for the Mac to enable this sort of pairing?

Thanks so much for your responses!

Comment: Well I'm not sure this is still relevant. However I do happen to have a custom library you could use if you would like to.

Comment: can I see it as well?

Comment: Do you explicitly want to establish a network connection between the two, or would some data-passing relationship work?